# clock with setInterval not updating time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The foll. is react docs code.
https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk?editors=0010

I am trying to run clock given by react docs in a local setup, with slight modifications, but the clock is displaying current time, without any increment in secs or mins.

// components/Clock.js

```
import React from 'react';

function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
 return element;
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);

export default tick;
```

// src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Clock from './components/Clock';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Clock />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

why the time is not updating ?

Comment: It's normal, when you render you're clock you're date is calculated one time. You've to refresh the clock component each seconds or store the time into a variable in your state. And here you're just exporting you're function the setInerval is not exported

Comment: @Alexis then how come https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk?editors=0010 is working, is it because it's directly updating  DOM using ReactDOM.
Do you mean I need to use container class to maintain state and use setState to update time ?

Comment: Just because you're exporting you're element without the set Interval so your `element` is render only one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample for you. Actually you have to use setInterval and need to store current time into state of the component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nuhgwi?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is not used in your version. You just export tick component. Move setInterval inside tick

Answer (score 0):

The right way in react would be

```
const myInterval; // Useful for manage and refer to the setinteval object
updateTime = () => setState({currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
startInterval = () =>  myInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

In render:

```
 <div>
    {this.state.currentTime}
 </div>
```